# CREATE RELATIONSHIP in cypher based on a conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two dates D1, D2 and a list of dates - DATESLIST. I want to create a relationship only when two conditions are satisfied.

1. All dates between D1 and D2 are not in DATESLIST
2. All dates between D1 and D2 are not weekends

the psuedocode of the same would look something like:

```
flag = 0
for d in range(D1, D2):
    if d not in DATESLIST and not d.isweekend():
       flag = 1
       break
if flag == 0:
   CREATE RELATIONSHIP
```

D1, D2 and DATESLIST are all obtained from as a result of a MATCH query.

I have thought of using apoc.do.when() along with a CALL construct, but I am unable to think of the syntax that would help me implement the flag and break logic.

Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please show us the query that you tried using apoc.do.when() then show us the error msg you are getting. Also, please give us examples of D1, D2, DATESLIST and the nodes/relationships you are creating

Answer (score 0):

My comments is that not all tools are suitable for all problems. Use the right tool for the job.

I would take your pseudo code and write the solution in another language (Java, Python, even BASH), and have this write to the DB. That way you can easily test it before hand to make sure the code is doing what you expect.